# Python - Multipart form data failed to authenticate using MultipartPostHandler library

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2, multipartform-data, python-2.6

I'm using the [MultipartPostHandler library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MultipartPostHandler/) for creating multi part-form data request.

I have face an issue and could be it requires an update in the library. We are using lighttpd web server and our cgi-bin folder is protected with username and password.

Whenever we need to use the cgi files from that folder we need to authenticate it with the username and password.

This works fine when there are NO parameters attached in the request but fails when there are any parameters associated in the request.

Could you please help me how shall i authenticate the url when using the parameters in the request ?

```
import MultipartPostHandler
import urllib2

def handle_authentication(url):
    """handle_authentication description"""
    try:
        passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        passman.add_password(None, url, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        print ERROR_300
        sys.exit(1)
```

another function:

```
params = {'BoardType': board_type,
          'SataConfigFile': open(input_path, 'rb')}
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
print opener
try:
    handle_authentication(url)
    response = opener.open(url, params)
```

This doesn't authenticate the URL - Do you have any solution with you ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the only issue, but it seems that you are not combining the openers properly. You will need to call build_opener with both the MultiPartPostHandler and the HttpBasicAuthHandler as arguments.

So instead of install_opener, try this:

```
import MultipartPostHandler
import urllib2

def build_authhandler(url):
    passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    passman.add_password(None, url, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
    return urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
```

and

```
params = {'BoardType': board_type,
          'SataConfigFile': open(input_path, 'rb')}
auth_opener = build_authhandler(url)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler, auth_opener)

try:    
    response = opener.open(url, params)
```